# Redirect URLs to Microsoft Edge even if I'm already in Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge

My objective is to force an URL to be opened in Microsoft Edge. I found a way to do this with : `microsoft-edge:url`.

The fact is that this method works under Internet Explorer, Chrome but NOT in Edge. Using this method in Edge will open a Bing search but not my link.

I'm encountering this issue because I want to change a link from a website and it doesn't work at all if I'm already in Edge.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `microsoft-edge:url` protocol enables other browsers to switch to Edge, except Edge itself since you're already in Edge. In this case, I would suggest modifying your code. You can first detect if the user is using Edge or other browsers. For other browsers, you can use `microsoft-edge:url` protocol; For Edge, you can simply use the url.

Comment: Yes I will just add like a browser check in my code. If the browser detected is not Edge, then simply redirect with `microsoft-edge:url` to Edge.